# Reverse an array with static method VS static void?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, void

I have found several threads how to reverse an array. However, I don't follow why can't use the same code for both a static method and a void method.

Can someone explain the difference in the following examples?

For a static method we can write:

```
public static double[] reverse (double[] a) 
{
        int n = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) 
        {
            double temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[n-(i+1)];
            a[n-(i+1)] = temp;
        }
        return a;
}
```

But for a static void we have:

```
public static void reverse (double[] a) 
{
    for (int i = 0, j = a.length-1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        double temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first case you are returning an array itself, in second case you just modify an existing array and return nothing

Comment: They are just two different ways of reversing an array, and the non-void method returns the array.

Comment: @Akceptor  Both methods modify the existing array.

Comment: @SteveSmith yeah, but void does not return it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Void and return in Java - when to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527555/void-and-return-in-java-when-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

First of all both methods in your case are static. They just have different return type

For the `static void reverse (double[] a)` case you do like this:

```
double[] arr = //some array
reverse(arr); //at this point arr is reversed so that you can use it 
reversedArr = arr; //or assign to different variable
```

Actually its ok if you have to reverse some internal array but I still don't like it because not too obvious the array is changed. I don't think its good to have such a method public...

`static double[] reverse (double[] a)` is good to be part of some utility class i.e.

```
double[] arr = //some array
reversedArr = ArrayUtils.reverse(arr); // now you can reuse method and you actually see that you changed the array
```

But you **should modify a method not to change initial array**, because you may run into trouble (calling an utility method should not modify the initial value)